# std::set_intersection elementary usage

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stl-algorithm

I practice the c++ standard library. Here is one problem I have with the usage of `set_intersection`:

I try to solve the problem 45 of project Euler:

> Triangle, pentagonal, and hexagonal numbers are generated by the following formulae:
>
> ```
> Triangle      Tn=n(n+1)/2     1, 3, 6, 10, 15, ...
> Pentagonal    Pn=n(3n−1)/2    1, 5, 12, 22, 35, ...
> Hexagonal     Hn=n(2n−1)      1, 6, 15, 28, 45, ...
> ```
>
> It can be verified that T285 = P165 = H143 = 40755.
>
> Find the next triangle number that is also pentagonal and hexagonal.

here is my tricks-free code for this:

```
using bint = unsigned long long;

auto pb045()->bint
{

    for (auto max_nb = 1024;; max_nb = max_nb << 1) {

            auto tris = std::vector<bint>{};
            tris.reserve(max_nb);

            auto pentas = std::vector<bint>{};
            pentas.reserve(max_nb);

            auto hexas = std::vector<bint>{};
            hexas.reserve(max_nb);
            for (auto i = 0; i < max_nb; i++) {
                    tris.push_back(i * (i + 1) / 2);
                    pentas.push_back(i * (3 * i - 1) / 2);
                    hexas.push_back(i * (2 * i - 1));
            }

            auto intersection1 = std::vector<bint>(max_nb);

            std::sort(tris.begin(), tris.end());
            std::sort(hexas.begin(), hexas.end());
            std::sort(pentas.begin(), pentas.end());

            auto 
                    begin = intersection1.begin(),
                    end =
            std::set_intersection(hexas.begin(), hexas.end(),
                                  pentas.begin(), pentas.end(),
                                  intersection1.begin());

            auto intersection = std::vector<bint>(end - begin);

            std::set_intersection(begin, end,
                                  tris.begin(), tris.end(),
                                  intersection.begin());

            if (intersection.size() > 3) {
                    // [0] -> 0
                    // [1] -> 1
                    _ASSERT(intersection[2] == 40755);
                    return intersection[3];
            }
    }
```

here:

- the algorithm does not gives the good solution
- if I comment the `sort` lines, it crashes (on MS VC++) with the message `sequence not ordered` in debug mode, and runs for long in release mode (but the numbers are inserted in increasing order, so the `sort` is useless).

I thinks that I miss something here.

Comment: what is with the title?

Comment: @Bot what do you mean?

Comment: the title is glitched with some kind of font or Latex

Comment: @mookid Most of what you have pasted above is irrelevant. For future questions, please follow the instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: actually it is an overflow problem, it has nothing to do with the usage of std::set_intersection.

Comment: [OT]: Mathematically, `T2n-1=(2n-1)(2n-1+1)/2=(2n-1)n=Hn`, so you may remove the triangle from equation.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes. That is why I said that no tricks of any kind were involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overflow for `pentas` when `i == 37838` (`i` is an `int`), so your array is no longer sorted by construction. You probably want `bint i`.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) assumes that the ranges passed to it are sorted. If you break that contract, the algorithm's output is no longer guaranteed to be meaningful. From what you describe, it is likely that the VC++ library implementation, in debug mode(based on `NDEBUG`, for example), checks that the input ranges satisfy this property. That is why you need to call `std::sort` before calling `std::set_intersection`.